# Is the inner product really needed in convex analysis?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In convex analysis, the Legendre-Fenchel transform seems to be always written as

$$
f^*(x^*) = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}\left\{\langle x, x^*\rangle - f(x)\right\},
$$

where $x$ and $x^*$ are both considered to be in the same vector space, namely $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is its inner product. The two main references, Fenchel and Rockafellar, both define it this way.

Another possible way to think about it would be to say that $x$ lives in an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$ and $x^*$ lives in its dual space, $V^*$. So we could write the Legendre-Fenchel transform as

$$
f^*(x^*) = \sup_{x\in V}\left\{x^* x - f(x)\right\},
$$

since a dual vector $x^*$ is a map sending a vector $x$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

My question is, does the inner product do any "real work" in convex analysis? That is, are there any important theorems that rely on $x$ and $x^*$ living in the same space, or which make use of the norm or the inner product in an important way?

Or to put it another way, if one were to avoid using the inner product and instead define everything in terms of dual spaces, **are there any important theorems in convex analysis that would no longer be meaningful and/or true?**

I have a feeling that it might just be a matter of historical taste, that people in convex analysis have tended to prefer to work $\mathbb{R}^n$ with an inner product rather than considering dual spaces. However, I am not sure and I would like to know if there is something that necessitates the inner product in the definition.

Comment: Since there is a natural inner product in $\Bbb R^n$, it's convenient to use it.

Comment: Of course - the question is whether convenience is the only reason.

Comment: The conjugate is defined more generally on the dual space, it does not require a Hilbert space. However, since convexity is almost inextricably tied up with a geometric view, one loses much value (in my opinion) with the extra generalisation.

Comment: The definition given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Definition) seems to be exactly as you say, defining $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ as a map $X^* \times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: My comment was from a pedagogical perspective. However, the conjugate finds many applications such as in control.

Comment: @copper.hat you can still take a geometric view without the inner product, at least for the parts of convex analysis that I've gone through in detail. The orientations of the non-vertical supporting planes are in a 1-1 correspondence with elements of the dual space - you just have to think of them as being specified by a linear map instead of by their normal vectors.

Comment: @JairTaylor that's a good catch. None of the references on that page seem to give a really deep formal treatment of the topic though.

Comment: @Nathaniel: That is true, but there are many more technicalities one needs to address when in an infinite dimensional space that are non issues in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Even with this simplification, Convex Analysis (as in Rockafellar) requires quite a bit of work.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm mostly only interested in the finite case for now. The issue is I'm trying to make a link to category theory, where people tend to think in terms of dual spaces even in the finite case, so it'll be more elegant if I can formulate it that way. I'm just worried that I've missed some important reason why the inner product needs to be used.

Comment: @Nathaniel: From a pure definition perspective it is not needed, but in 'practical' use having, for example, a strictly convex unit ball is useful for having various unique solutions.

Comment: @copper.hat right, it's that kind of thing that I'm asking about - what theorems do I not have if I don't use the inner product? If you're able to list some of the unique solution results you mention in your last comment, that would make a great answer.

Comment: You should read Ekeland and Temam, which develops some parts of convex analysis in a vector space which is not necessarily an inner product space. Great book.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you *need* the inner product, especially if you're working on optimization problems in Banach spaces, in which there is no guaranteed inner product. Although practically it goes without saying that the inner product endows a lot of structure to the space you're working in. I digress, to think about the Legendre-Fenchel transform, regardless of dimensionality, in the context of dual spaces is similar to what you said: for any function $f:X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, where $X$ is a real linear locally convex space, you can define its conjugate function, $f^*$, on the dual space, $X^*$, $f^*:X^*\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ by:
$$ f^*(x^*)=\sup\{(x^*,x)-f(x),\quad x\in X\},
\quad x^*\in X^*$$
where for two linear spaces $X$ and $Y$ over the same scalar field $F$ you define a dual system if a fixed bilinear functional on their product is given:
$$ (\cdot, \cdot ): X\times Y\to F$$
For each $x\in X$, we define the application $f_x:Y \to F$ by 
$$ f_x(y)=(x,y), \quad \forall y\in Y$$
Notice that $f_x$ is a linear functional on $Y$, and the mapping $x\to f_x \quad \forall x\in X$ is linear and injective, so the elements of X can be identified with the linear functionals on Y. In a similar manner the elements of $Y$ can be identified with the linear functionals on $X$. Thus each dual system of linear spaces defines a mapping from either of the two linear spaces into the space of linear functionals on the other. In other words, there is a natural duality between $X$ and $X^*$ determined by the bilinear functional $(\cdot, \cdot):X\times X^*\to F$, defined by
$$ (x,x^*)=x^*(x), \quad \forall x\in X, x^* \in X^*$$
A great reference that helped me formalize my understanding of this for a personal problem is Barbu and Precupanu's *Convexity and Optimization in Banach Spaces*. So that might be useful if you're looking for a formal treatment of this topic. For example, they present the derivation of the dual problem for a linear program in finite dimensions, and for a linear program where dimension is not concerned, among other generalizations. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, that reference looks very good.